# No matching call for default ctor

Tags: c++, struct, unordered-map, default-constructor

Why is default ctor of struct range required at Line 16 (mentioned in code below)?

My code :

```
struct range {
    int begInd, endInd, fr;
    range(int b, int e, int f) : begInd(b), endInd(e), fr(f) {}
    //range() {}   /* COMPILE SUCCESS if this line is uncommented */
};

class Solution {
public:
    int findShortestSubArray(vector<int>& nums) {
        unordered_map<int, range> freq;
        int i, minLen = INT_MAX, maxFreq;
        for (i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            if (freq.find(nums[i]) == freq.end())
                freq.insert(make_pair(nums[i], range(i, i, 1)));
            else {
                freq[nums[i]].endInd = i;   // Line 16
                freq[nums[i]].fr++;
            }
        } // more code after this...
```

Compile error (leetcode is not letting me copy the error, so image) : 
    [image]

Last 3 lines of error :
Line 16: Char 29:     required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/tuple:1668:70: error: no matching function for call to 'range::range()'
second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)

My understanding : Since no new node is being created in unordered_map at line 16, there shouldn't be any need of ctor of any type.
I also checked [unordered_map::operator[] on Cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/), but didn't find anything on such case.

Comment: @Steve But the condition 'map does not already contains such an object' would be evaluated at runtime. Why a compile time error?

Comment: @G_S yes, but if there is a branch that requires a default constructor, then you need a default constructor.

Comment: @G_S because it can't know that at compile time, and therefore it needs to know how to default-construct the element in case it's needed at runtime.

Comment: Yes you need to post as text not as an image

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Updated. See just below image.